# Getting text from online file via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the following JSON data: https://beta.ngs.noaa.gov/gtkws/geo?northing=76470.584%20&easting=407886.482&zone=3702

However, JQuery doesn't seem to be able to retrieve it. I believe this is due to the data being stored as a 'file' instead of a JSON file. Being fairly new to Javascript, I've ran out of ideas for retrieving the data. Do you all have any ideas?

Comment: `$.getJSON("https://beta.ngs.noaa.gov/gtkws/geo?northing=76470.584%20&easting=407886.482&zone=3702")` seems to work just fine for me. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @Hamms in a browser? I am getting CORS rejections.

Comment: The only version of getJSON that I'm familiar with required a function passed to it. For this one, how do I go about saving the JSON object to a variable?

Comment: Ah, right you are Olivia; running a browser does indeed give CORS errors

Answer (score -1):

Do you have errors in your console? It looks like that site is not setting any kind of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers, so your browser is likely denying the request for security reasons.

If that is the case, you likely cannot access it in the browser without modifying their server. You could fetch it via your server and relay it to the browser that way though.

Comment: Thank you for answering! How did you check the permissions? There are a few other options for me to get the coordinates, and I'd like to check them too.

Comment: I use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to simulate REST requests. I add a header for `Origin` to the outgoing request, and look for an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response. If it is not there, a browser will not be able to call it from a different domain.